# Output HTML in ReactJS with onClick function on a live search div

Tags: javascript, search, reactjs

What is the correct way to output a `<li>` item for a `<ul>` on a live search using ReactJS?

I'm using `$("#livesearchdesc").html(rows.join(""));` in order to populate the `<ul>`, but the problem comes when it tries to add the rows array.

The rows array is populated like this:

```
rows.push(
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" value={item.iditem} ref="iditemsearch" />
    <input type="hidden" value={item.descripcion} ref="descripcionsearch" />
    <a onClick={this.clickLi}>item.iditem item.descripcion</a>
  </li>
)
```

I've tried to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rows}}` but it doesn't work for me.

Do you know anything I can do in order to fix this problem?

Comment: React doesn't return DOM elements. Look at `React.render` or example.

Comment: Hello WiredPrairie. I also tried `React.render` but I couldn't get what I want. Do you have any example? Thank you

Comment: The docs cover this pretty well, so without adding more context to your question, I don't know what to add. http://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Sorry but I'm stucked on this!! can you help me with a little yet complete example of what you are trying to explain?

Comment: `React.render(rows, document.getElementById('libesearchdesc'));` for example. Although, the `rows` might not work exactly ...,.